# PHP RegEx - Remove from char to char?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I have this string:

```
http://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn2/t1/c22.0.100.100/p100x100/1489204_568091786618712_2075358603_n.jpg
```

I want to remove following part of the string:

```
c22.0.100.100/p100x100/
```

... But following part of the string is dynamic (changes):

```
c22.0.100.100
```

I'm thinking that it might be possible to use the PHP `preg_` function in combination with a regular expression i some way? **Example:** Remove backwards from `/p100x100/` to next `/` ??

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: you know the string you want to remove is alway starts at the 5th / and ends at the 7th.  should take you less than 10 seconds to come up with a solution from there without even bothering up with a regex

Comment: You must give more examples of how `c22.0.100.100` can change

Comment: I have a solution. But this is basic, try out some regexes (if you need them, `explode()` should suffice) and come back with code you've written

Comment: Thank you for quick replies guys. Can you come up with solutions? Im not very familiar with regex's. Casimir another example could be: c170.0.100.100 and c19.0.100.100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CODE:

```
  $a = 'http://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn2/t1/c22.0.100.100/p100x100/1489204_568091786618712_2075358603_n.jpg';;
  $b = preg_replace("/[^\/]*\/p100x100\//",'',$a);
  echo 'A: '.$a."\n";
  echo 'B: '.$b."\n";
```

This regex `[^\/]*\/p100x100\/` replaces...

- `[^\/]*` as many non-'/'
- `\/p100x100\/` followed by /p100x100/
- `''` with nothing

OUTPUT:

```
A: http://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn2/t1/c22.0.100.100/p100x100/1489204_568091786618712_2075358603_n.jpg
B: http://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn2/t1/1489204_568091786618712_2075358603_n.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('¦/t1/.*/p100x100/¦', '/t1/', $string)
```

could throw some funny problems though using .* but without any other information on what the replaceable string could be it's the best that can be done.

what's your final aim of this? what does it do, what does it need to do, and why, these are all pieces of the puzzle that will help people answer :)

Comment: Thank you Ben. I'll be back tomorrow.. "/t1/" isnt always part of the string :-(

Comment: `preg_replace('~[^/]+/p100x100/~', '', $string);` I haven't tried it out, but it might work to remove those two directories. It might require some tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this to remove the `c22.0.100.100/p100x100/`

```
<?php
$str="http://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn2/t1/c22.0.100.100/p100x100/1489204_568091786618712_2075358603_n.jpg";

    echo preg_replace('~(?<=t1).*(?=\/)~',"",$str);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/93000)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
preg_replace('~/c\d+(?:\.\d+){3}/p100x100\b~', '', $str)
```